# What is the [character-development] tag for?

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-wiki

We have 23 questions with the [character-development](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/character-development) tag. The tag has no description and by looking over the questions I'm not getting a good idea of how the tag links them.

What does the tag [character-development](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/character-development) cover which the related tags do not:

- [character-creation](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/character-creation) for "realizing a character concept within the rules of an RPG"
- [character-advancement](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/character-advancement) about progression within a system

If there is some use/meaning of this tag which I'm not seeing, can we get a description for it? Otherwise, should we re-tag the questions and burninate or synonymize this one?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Character development is a narrative term: it's literally developing someone's character further. That means learning more about them through expressing new things, or their character changing their ideas or behaviours, among other things. It's not mechanical, so it's not covered by those tags, although it may have mechanical ramifications sometimes.

One famous pop culture example of character development was when Neo decided to turn around and fight Agent Smith. Wow! He wouldn't have done that earlier. Suddenly his character has developed.

Sometimes this is also called character growth.

[How to transform a tragic hero into a villain?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/15486/how-to-transform-a-tragic-hero-into-a-villain) is an exemplary question of this tag.

You can read more about character development here: [*What does Character development actually mean?* on Writing Stack Exchange](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/2974/what-does-character-development-actually-mean)

Comment: See also the info for the tag on writing: https://writing.stackexchange.com/tags/character-development/info

Comment: In your estimation, are the questions that currently have the tag using it correctly? (At a glance, some of them seemed like they were intending to use one of the other two tags mentioned in the question, and had little to do with character development in this sense.)

Comment: @V2Blast Some of them should be retagged.

Comment: As a matter of record, a tag description based on this answers definition as been created and questions are being retagged (if you find any questions with this tag which shouldn't, do please retag them. I've therefore marked this as accepted.